# Dimension $\mathbb {R}(\mathbb {C})$ versus dimension $\mathbb {C}(\mathbb {R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, extension-field, tensor-products, tensors

I was reading notes about tensor products and the author said that $\operatorname{\dim}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}) = 4$ while $\operatorname{\dim}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C})$ is not defined, but it is not clear to me why this is true. Could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: Forget about the tensor products, this is just because every complex vector space can be viewed as a real space (because $\Bbb C \cong \Bbb R^2$), but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a prequel, if $V,W$ are two vector spaces over the same field $F$ then the tensor product $V \otimes_F W$ is also a field over $F$, and so the dimension of $V \otimes_F W$ over $F$ is defined. Let's call this operation "tensor product over $F$" (and its dimension over $F$ is the product of the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ over $F$).

So, for example, in the tensor product $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb C} \mathbb C$, both $\mathbb C$ factors are vector spaces over $\mathbb C$, and you are tensoring over $\mathbb C$, the tensor product is also a vector space over $\mathbb C$, so this is tensor product over $\mathbb C$, and its dimension over $\mathbb C$ is defined (and is equal to $1 \times 1 = 1$).

To get to your question, in the tensor product $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$ both factors are vector spaces over $\mathbb R$, and you are tensoring over $\mathbb R$, so this is tensor product over $\mathbb R$. The dimension over $\mathbb R$ is defined (and is equal to $2 \cdot 2 = 4$).

But the "tensor product over $\mathbb C$" construction does not work on $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$, because *$\mathbb R$ is not $\mathbb C$*.

Nonetheless, there is a different construction (which I overlooked in my original version of this answer; thanks to @Thorgott for the correction). Namely if $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$, and if $E$ is an extension field of $F$, then $V \otimes_F E$ does indeed have a natural vector space structure over $E$. This is not the same operation as "tensor product over $F$", you can think of this instead as "extension of scalars from $F$ to $E$" (and its dimension over $E$ is equal to the dimension of $V$ over $F$).

So, $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$ may indeed be thought of as a vector space over $\mathbb C$ by using the operation of extension of scalars (and its dimension over $\mathbb C$ is equal to the dimension of $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb R$ which is $2$).

Comment: I don't quite agree. There is a canonical $\mathbb{C}$-vector space structure on $V\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$ for any $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $V$ given by scalar multiplying in the second factor. This is an extension of scalars.

Comment: Hmmm... that's a good point that I should have thought of... I'll have to think how I want to reword that paragraph......

Comment: The tensor construction for modules is such that if $S, T, R$ are rings, and $_SM_R$ and $_RN_T$ are bimodules over the rings as indicated in the subscripts, then $M\otimes_R N$ is a $S-T$ bimodule.   So in this also yields a $\mathbb C$ structure on $\mathbb C\otimes_\mathbb R V$ for any real vector space $V$.

Comment: Regardless of the ways in which $\Bbb C \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$ can in fact be considered a vector space over $\Bbb C$, it seems apparent that the author of the notes mentioned in the OP was not aware of them when remarking that $\dim_{\Bbb C}(\Bbb C \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C)$ is not defined. Thus this answer still accurately addresses the question, if not quite in the originally intended manner.

Comment: Should not it be stated clearly that we are in the case of finite dimensional vector spaces? or it is understandable?

Comment: What about " $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C )$?" how can we deal with this ...... I understood what you said above and I found I theorem that exactly says what you said but I am still confused about  $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C )$ because I am trying to find the dimension over $\mathbb R$ and not $\mathbb C $ as in the question.

Comment: In general, from the case I mentioned in my previous comment, I am confused about how to look at the problem as a tensor product or extension of scalars. Could you clarify this please?

Comment: But the theorem I referred to in my comment above requires that $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space , here is the statement of the theorem  "Let $V$ be a finite d.v.s over $F,$ and $F \subseteq K$ is a field, then $$\operatorname{dim}_{F} V = \operatorname{dim}_{K} ( V \otimes_{ F} K)$$  "

Comment: @LeeMosher here is the link to my question I asked in it the same questions in my previous comments (in case you want to answer it there) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4429445/operatornamedim-mathbb-c-mathbb-c-otimes-mathbb-r-mathbb-c-vs-o