# $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb C} \mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$ vs. $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, extension-field, tensor-products, tensors

Here is the spaces I am trying to find their dimensions:

$1- \operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C)$

$2-\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C)$

**For the first one**, I am convinced with what @LeeMosher told me here in his answer [Dimension $\mathbb {R}(\mathbb {C})$ versus dimension $\mathbb {C}(\mathbb {R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4417272/dimension-mathbb-r-mathbb-c-versus-dimension-mathbb-c-mathbb-r) ,  I just have a small question, which is:

Should not it be stated clearly that we are in the case of finite dimensional vector spaces? or it is understandable? as I am using the following theorem (which I do not know if it is also correct for infinite dimensional vector spaces or no):

"Let $V$ be a finite d.v.s over $F,$ and $F \subseteq K$ is a field, then $\operatorname{dim}_{F} V = \operatorname{dim}_{K} ( V \otimes_{ F} K).$"

**For the second one,** I am confused how to find its dimension and should I consider it as a tensor product or should it be an extension of scalars? Also, a friend of mine told me that the dimension of the second one is 1 but I could not understand why.

Could anyone help me in answering these questions please?

Comment: The dimension of the second one is $ 4 $, and not $ 1 $.

Comment: For the second one, you should simply forget that $\mathbb C$ is a field. Treat it like you would any 2d real vector space.

Comment: Do you know how a basis for $V$ and $W$ can be turned into a basis for $V\otimes W$?

Comment: @CraniumClamp Ok, thanks! for pointing out that it was a mistake

Comment: Okay! will do @Vercassivelaunos

Comment: yeah, just multiply them by each other @runway44

Answer (score 2):

As stated for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Dimension), since $\mbox{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{C}) = 2$, you have that $\mbox{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \right) = \mbox{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{C})^2 = 4$.

The first one is, in a sense, ill-defined, since $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ does not have a clear structure of $\mathbb{C}$-vector field (if you multiply an element by $i$, does it multiply the left-hand side ? or the right-hand side ?) However, once you fix this by defining it clearly, you must have $\mbox{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}\left( \mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \mbox{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \right) = 2$.